# How to implement negative lookahead regex match in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I need to implement a regex pattern equivalent to **^12(?!34)** which using negative lookahead in MySQL. But MySQl does not support negative lookahead.

So is it possible to implement such pattern in MySQL that start with **12** and not followed by **34**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the alternation operator when a negative lookahead is missing:

```
^12([0-24-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-35-9])
```